# Gap fill: “Eventually”, “finally”, “ultimately” or “conclusively”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, collocation

Which word fits best in the following sentence:

> "Secondly, the ability to judge a character is vital, since a witness's response to a question may be more significant than the answer given. (**9**) _______, leadership qualities are fundamental. Top lawyers do not have the time to do all the research necessary in a case by themselves"

**Eventually / finally / ultimately / conclusively**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Can you provide a context for this usage? What exactly are you trying to convey? What research have you done, which choice do you think is best, and why?

Comment: This sentence is the last but not least point in the list of arguments. It seems to me Finally fits best. But I am not sure

Comment: *Fundamental* to what, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. Yes, go with "Finally."

Comment: Because the previous two sentences begin with **Firstly** and **Secondly**, it's plausible to assume the third should start with **Finally**, as @MarkHubbard suggested.

Comment: So, only Finally can go with the list of arguments or can I use some other words in this case?

Comment: **Conclusively** is close to acceptable, but would only be applicable if the whole paragraph can be summed up using the phrase "leadership qualities are fundamental"

Comment: If you were trying to express the idea "In the final analysis" (as opposed to "Lastly in the series of three numbered points"), "Ultimately" would be a legitimate choice. But I agree with Hank that the inclusion of "Firstly" and "Secondly" as introductory words to the previous two sentences strongly suggests that "Thirdly of three"—that is "Lastly" or "Finally"—is the sense you are supposed to  infer at blank number 9.

Answer (score 4):

*Eventually, leadership qualities are fundamental* = Not poor English, but a weak thought. At the beginning, those qualities don't matter, but only *after a long time*?

*Finally, leadership qualities are fundamental* = As my *closing* thought in this paper, let me point out that leadership qualities are fundamental. **In the context of the paragraph, that is your best fit.**

*Ultimately, leadership qualities are fundamental* = In looking at *the big picture*, leadership qualities are fundamental.

*Conclusively, leadership qualities are fundamental* = This paper draws *the solid conclusion* that leadership qualities are fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Since the previous sentences start with "Firstly" and "Secondly", Question 9 should start with "Finally" as it is the last point.

> Finally, leadership qualities are fundamental